# Why Xcode size is become almost double?

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125). It's too slow when booting simulator. I have deleted unwanted simulators. Now I do have only 3 simulators and Xcode size shows the almost 11.84GB. It's double compare when downloaded size.

See the pic.
[image]

I tried following -

1- deleting unavailable devices - `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`

2- No run time profiles created. Infact there is no folder available. `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`

3- Only having these SDK files -

```
iPhoneSimulator.sdk iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk
```

at location

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
```

4 - Trying to delete the corresponding .dmg file

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads
```

but found No such file or directory.

Let me know how to make Xcode lightweight. Is there something that I could delete and decrease it.

Comment: You could try to delete all unavailable devices (those that are not supported by the current Xcode SDK) with `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`. They are not part of the Xcode bundle but in my case, it helped to regain a fair amount of space in my system.

Comment: How to get list of unavailable devices lists before deleting? @Alladinian

Comment: I don't think there's an option for this. I guess you could try `xcrun simctl list` to list them all, then `xcrun simctl list devices available` to list the available ones and finally crosscheck them somehow.

Comment: Only 4 devices I have I guess. == Devices ==
-- iOS 12.2 --
    iPhone 6s Plus (35DCE237-0FD9-4030-A600-9FF88B680E1F) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 Plus (E22B7813-2D31-4361-AB0B-2ED336C98FE8) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone XR (CE7316DB-A29F-4E43-A5E9-CCA69F5488DE) (Shutdown) 
-- tvOS 12.2 --
-- watchOS 5.2 -- @Alladinian

Comment: I have deleted unavailable devices previously. still the size is bigger.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check what I tried till time. @Alladinian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded a compressed file. When installing Xcode, the compressed file is expanded. That's why Xcode is double the size of the compressed file. Outside of deleting simulators, which you already did, there isn't anything else you can do to reduce the Xcode app size.